# Passing state with useContext in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the useContext hook to pass state and setState to a child component but I'm getting a ts error when I try and pass [state, setState] in the value argument of the provider. My code is as follows:

```
export interface IProviderProps {
  children?: any;
}

const initialState = {
  state: Object,
  setState: () => {},
};

export const AppContext = createContext(initialState);

export const AppProvider = (props: IProviderProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([{ isMenuOpen: false, isSideOpen: false }]);

  return <AppContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>{props.children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};
```

I'm getting an error on the value variable about the `initialState` I'm setting.

`index.d.ts(290, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ state: ObjectConstructor; setState: () => void; }>'`

What do I set the initial state as to allow me to pass the state and useState variables?

Comment: Try `value={{state, setState}}`

Comment: No joy. `AppContext.tsx(8, 3): The expected type comes from property 'state' which is declared here on type '{ state: ObjectConstructor; setState: () => void; }`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

TypeScript infers the `AppContext` type from `initialState` given to `createContext`.

`AppContext.Provider` expects a `value` prop, that matches above type. So the type instantiated by `createContext` determines the context shape, consuming components can use.

### What went wrong?

`initialState` gets following inferred type:

```
{ state: ObjectConstructor; setState: () => void; }
```

Passing `Object` to `state` means, you expect  an `ObjectConstructor` - not really what you want. With `setState: () => {}`, components are not able to invoke this function with a `state` argument. Also note, `useState` initial value is currently wrapped in an additional array `[{...}]`.

In summary, `[state, setState]` argument  is incompatible to `AppContext.Provider` value prop.

---

### Solution

Let's assume, your desired state shape looks like:

```
type AppContextState = { isMenuOpen: boolean; isSideOpen: boolean }
// omitting additional array wrapped around context value
```

Then an initial state with proper types is ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAERSoYsCwAUL0gA9IsOMAB2lKHXRUAkgAVGAN2AATJFEUQwhXLzgG4aABbAANqvZiA-AC44KMQE8A3L2q9eMJ2CoBBMDAAYQgJQRgyCioAXlxRQgBZJDF8AHlfMXsAIwgIM1QxF3iSNSR05Ozc-McaXgB6OrgmYBgYcQBzB1VVFuBQlDMHKCgUJzgAdxHApFUhiHwxWbRQygF4JQH8JE8eBrgrFBAZuAADcV6ByMoTuBgIU5RAoJgBABEkaXwzGAA1TaQbnc4FkqChgS04CBoFRlmI0MBiLxYYR4I9gi93p9vn8zFs4LEcPpDCiovY8Aikilypl6ANiNgESV1NT7NIzMQaJgiQZiBFyJR7AAKEkCuABYIrcJXJAASnxAD44rQ9mJcmA4OosfA0AMzFl0ABrdxuPg8QTCbWhFFip6Stb4xAcGAAOjQ7CiITCa0FaOebw%20KC%20v3%20MpN-CE0EtYmt4q0KnUUAdgrAjB09gUylKmlThDl0UVhJ4hiMVvgAG0RUhsLzpQBdB1EUj8pA%20p4YgNBnFbZ2V0M7YvsGD4KBiOCC7nFuAAHnFntWLrjWbgG1xSGiODwlerSD5URo1HlE8nhhwKe0hFdpgsVg8ReP07qs7tC8zCcPd4MfZ41BcQA)):

```
// renamed `initialState` to `appCtxDefaultValue` to be a bit more concise
const appCtxDefaultValue = {
  state: { isMenuOpen: false, isSideOpen: false },
  setState: (state: AppContextState) => {} // noop default callback
};

export const AppContext = createContext(appCtxDefaultValue);

export const AppProvider = (props: IProviderProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(appCtxDefaultValue.state);

  return (
    // memoize `value` to optimize performance, if AppProvider is re-rendered often 
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

A more explicit variant with own context value type ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecAiwAzmCjGgBbYDKSM1MZSAghsBAHbYCuRSDTOAF84AMygQQcAERRUGaQFgAUCqQAPSLDjAOMJFFHokcAJIAFCQDdgAEwOWIYIrhVx3cSsAA2tuRwB%20AC44FA4ATwBuFSEVFRhwsBNmMDAAYU59dXpGfTgAXlwdIgBZJA5uAHkkjhCAIwgIb1QOSOLqOyRq8vrG5rDhFQB6IbhJYBgYXQBzUNtbCfYOFG9QqCgUcLgAdw3UpFs1iG4OQ7RMjXgrFe4kOOUEpLgU9IvsgDUbk0KcNw8iXJIEIvDJ6S4CfTRZQeOAjOCPJDYcLHODTOg7CjlOAUCBWAwzMZ4qBwAAGfByTBJYgkUhJvH4gJJf3c5IhQIIxFI5AoAB5aBT9KwppweSC3gKkAA%20SVQoRQlTnDgA0KpNIwdT4JBGbjeGCfby3YGq8X624FVzQ-6AkJ4YhlCrdWpiFZ8bDEDr2R0hIzePjCTDMuCs61BwEFSVFERwjiNMBweza3WeFbeOroADWMXlyg0WngiuVYrB2XNyHQMAAdGg5ExQVkYAAKFCq9WaxN6r4ASmzueg%20c4hdSjhs9mJhQbYAkzhCFmsnSgjmcnfDFphBfgAG0AUxsMGmABdc30tlNlsarUoHUdg1ICvb-Td%204wuQwbhQDhwBuBmGi43FyvDvOcDXDe%20Q4Hg96IkGdBssIQiSt%20MIeDgk5OEQVYUD4fjlLElpIXAPJDEW9YVoBo4IXhcCPsocpAA)):

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, /* and others */ } from "react";

type AppContextValue = {
  state: AppContextState;
  // type, you get when hovering over `setState` from `useState`
  setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<AppContextValue>>;
};

const appCtxDefaultValue: AppContextValue = {/* ... */};
```

---

### Discussing alternatives

#### Drop context default value completely ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=36&ssc=2&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecAiwAzmCjGgBbYDKSM1MZSAghsBAHbYCuRSDTHnwDCnGEgAe8AL5wAZlAgg4AIiioMKgLAAoXZMiw4wDuKhz0SOAEkACooBuwACZIo9iGCK5dcP3EpgABtndQ4AfgAuOBQOAE8Abl1pXV0YOLArZjAwUVNJekZxOABeXGMiAFkkDm4AeUyOaIAjCAgg1A4EiuoXJAaalraO2LgUvR10zLhs3LECgDUUIO4rMpxffyIipGjZvPEpAXEknX84PkKmaMISMkoAHlor8VYYdg4H-fmjnYA%20P6naSnfQSQzwNCcbYzHIHAqlRAaGAAOjQ6iYcKkX1hPxgSxWVgAPnBuBxXHITEhnH8ABSk8mU5wAShBOgM0AhUPgsw8TlcUARNLAii80Tsjj67hFRCZpT%20PjO-khHGhAG1toILnRjkgALoI3j8HY0vDEaq1AZNeTLPjYYi9VyW6IWIJ8MYs1KKvzqGDcKAcOA0zbnPzYub5KTI3mSuAOZarEo4PAa8TYS46sbSP7BkPnHDCzxEVEUYKhGrjXOhgD03wjKOj-OzXrgHp0wM9clJbE4JL4tcOMBpso2zeV0IwEnxqwNIlxNP7BSZOeAckDE6naxKZXpSApHCpspgFEUAHc4PuzwBRKCKKBB5vnFSXsFIDBUmIBnkS-kXJRIE8UG4VgmHAR5WOiGCgeoVgwBAWqcnWsbxkgKhLs2Pp%20gG67IXAVZVueEBnhQKDeFMWQ4nWG45nhcDQHASAODUcAFnyVjOEoKAgSAdAUBAzjeHIdHNHQZj0RwaAoF43BBGQHzJJ6Y7wMIQTADU8BlEOcoKucikBDAk7LDOLAUQOmk0dhQQVHADL7s42AcHBlCvgA1uer5IEQRAoFAcQAITJEAA))

```
export const AppContext = React.createContext<AppContextValue | undefined>(undefined);

export const AppProvider = (props: IProviderProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ isMenuOpen: false, isSideOpen: false });
    // ... other render logic
};
```

To prevent, that a client now has to check for `undefined`, provide a custom Hook:

```
function useAppContext() {
    const ctxValue = useContext(AppContext)
    if (ctxValue === undefined) throw new Error("Expected context value to be set")
    return ctxValue // now type AppContextValue
    // or provide domain methods instead of whole context for better encapsulation
}

const Client = () => {
    const ctxVal = useAppContext() // ctxVal is defined, no check necessary!
}
```

#### Switch to `useReducer` and/or custom `useAppContext` Hook

Consider to replace `useState` by `useReducer` and pass the `dispatch` function down to components. This will provide better encapsulation, as the state manipulation logic is now centralized in a pure reducer and child components *cannot* manipulate it directly anymore via `setState`.

Another very good alternative to separate UI Logic from domain logic is to provide a custom `useAppContext` Hook instead of using `useContext(AppContext)` - see previous example. Now `useAppContext` can provide a more narrow API without publishing your whole context.

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helped. I used the first example, the second may come in handy when I get to grips with Dispatch.

Comment: Hi, I am also suffering from this error. but In your reply it is not clear to me how to use the AppProvider. Because there are not values given here. How can the components the state and setState values from the AppProvider? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @g00golplex `AppProvider` can be used like this with `MyComp` (continuation of first example):  `const MyComp = () => { const {state,setState} = useContext(AppContext); ... }
const App = () => <AppProvider> <MyComp /> </AppProvider>`

Comment: Hi Ford04! Thank you very much for your feedback! I really needed time to get it implemented ( yes I am a n00b in React and TypeScript) I finally got it to work!

Comment: You're a god man, your explanation was on point!

Comment: I wanna set the state like this

`setState(prev => ({...prev, isMenuOpen: true}))`

but it gives me this error

`Parameter 'prev' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
Argument of type '(prev: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AppContextState'.(2345)
(parameter) prev: any`

pls suggest me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a satisfactory and easy solution is to create an additional function, that can setState.
Example:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext(
    { 
    checked: true,
    loggedIn: false, 
    changeLoggedIn: (logged: boolean) => {} 
    });

const AuthContextProvider = (props: { children: React.ReactElement }) => {
    const [checked, setchecked] = React.useState(true);
    const [loggedIn, setloggedIn] = React.useState(false);

    const changeLoggedIn = (logged: boolean) => {
        setloggedIn(logged);
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, checked, changeLoggedIn }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContextProvider
```