# How can I properly define a type interface when using React useContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I have:

```
export interface AppStateType {
    isOnline: boolean
}

const AppContext = createContext([{}, () => { }]);

const AppProvider = (props) => {
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState<AppStateType>({
        isOnline: true
    })

    return <AppContext.Provider value={[appState, setAppState]}>
        {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
}
export { AppContext, AppProvider }
```

When when I try to use it:

```
const [appState, setAppState] = useContext<AppStateType>(AppContext)
```

I get a Typescript error:

```
Argument of type 'Context<{}[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<AppStateType>'.
  The types of 'Provider.propTypes.value' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Validator<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<AppStateType>'.
      Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'AppStateType'.
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193424/passing-state-with-usecontext-in-typescript/58199140#58199140) probably will help you - it is the same constellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because the return type of Context is not an `AppStateType` but an array with two values. **First is AppState** and **second is a dispatcher**

With typescript you can type the context when its created like

```
const AppContext = createContext<[AppStateType, React.Dispatch<any>]>(null);
```

Post this, you can simply use it like

```
const [appState, setAppState] = useContext(AppContext);
```

[Sample Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-usecontext-example-7cefc?file=/src/Context.tsx)

**NOTE:** Define the default value to createContext as null since it would only be used when there is no provider in the hierarchy tree. In which case it mostly might be an error

Comment: What error does it throw, because it compiles well for me if I create context like `const AppContext = createContext<[AppStateType, React.Dispatch<any>]>(null);` Make sure you pass null to createContext as arguments because that will only be used if no PRovider is available in the hierachy which means your code is incorrect so it better throw an error than go unnoticed

Comment: yeah, passing `null` instead of `[]` is an option. But it depends on the environment - it is only possible with `strict` mode / `strictNullChecks` option disabled, which is the case in the sandbox (you can try adding `"strictNullChecks": true` to tsconfig.json).

Comment: Hmm, it still works even if I add `strictNullChecks` in TS config

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-61775657-xdq8f?file=/src/Context.tsx) is a copy of your sandbox, where those checks are activated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for createContext is the default value of the context see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)
So if your context type is the state and set state like so

```
[AppStateType,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AppStateType>>]
```

You need to give a default value

```
const AppContext = createContext([{}, () => { }]);
```

Should be

```
const AppContext = createContext<[AppStateType,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AppStateType>>]>([{isOnline:false},()=> false]);
```

Comment: Then I can't set the appState

Comment: @Shamoon You're right I updated my answer to have an array of State and sSetState as type for context allowing the array to be passed as the value