# UseContext provider not working in office JS addin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-js

I am trying to develop addins for excel using React and TypeScript. I have the following App return statement:

```js
export default  class App extends React.Component<AppProps, FeedBackMessages> {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    const { title, isOfficeInitialized } = this.props;
    if (!isOfficeInitialized) {
      return (
        <Progress title={title} logo="assets/Boxes32x32.png" message="Please sideload your addin to see app body." />
      );
    }
    
    return (
      <Stack>
      {/* this context provider is needed to share the context hook for feedback messages */}
      <FeedbackProvider>
      <Stack.Item align="center">
        <h2> Profile generator</h2>
      </Stack.Item>
       </FeedbackProvider>
      </Stack>
    );
  }
}
```

The feedback provider looks like this:

```js
export interface IProviderProps {
  children?:any;
 
}
//create the object for the message state 
type MessageContextState = {
 message: string; 
 messageType: string; 
 mVisible:boolean;
/*  onConfirm?: () => void,
 onCancel?: () => void */
}
//object to define the message and setMessage
const messageContextValue = {
 fbMessage: {message: "Message from the context", messageType: "default", mVisible: false},
 setFbMessage: (fbMessage: MessageContextState)=>{ }
};

export interface FeedBackMessages {
 message: string,
 messageType: string,
 mVisible : boolean
} 
 //this is initializing the context with default values
export const FeedbackContext = React.createContext(messageContextValue);

//this replaces FeedbackContext.Provider in the app
export const FeedbackProvider = (props:IProviderProps)=>{
 const [fbMessage, setFbMessage] = useState(messageContextValue.fbMessage);
  return(
  <FeedbackContext.Provider value ={{ fbMessage, setFbMessage}}>
    {props.children}
  </FeedbackContext.Provider>
  )


}
```

The Snippet above was made with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193424/passing-state-with-usecontext-in-typescript/58199140?noredirect=1#comment112378809_58199140) post and it works fine with the CRA boilerplate in Chrome or Firefox. But when I sideload the app in Excel it returns a blank page. If I remove `FeedbackProvider`, I get the content back. I have no idea where to look. Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advnce

Comment: Please fill the blank before the comma in your sentence beginning "If I remove ,". If it is code, you might need to put it inside backticks.

Comment: My Bad!  I Used <FeedbackProvider> but the string parser removed it. sorry.

Comment: Hi, I think I found the error it is throwing: SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol.iterator'. But in Chrome or Firefox this error is not thrown. So I think I have to add a Polyfill for the symbol.iterator. But until now, I could not find the way to do that. I already included core-js, installed @babel/polyfill, entered core-js/modules/es/array.iterator in the webpack.config.js. So Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there nobody who has an answer for that? How do all office add-in developers cope with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem although it is not clear to me why it works. I first tried to get all the Polyfills working with Core-js. Because apparently it has something to do with IE not being able to understand EC6. But to no avail. whatever I tried, it did not work. So what I did was I re-wrote the context provider so it does not initialize a value. Now the error disappeared and it works:

```
enter   //when using the modern React call, the taskpane app will flinch. so it has to be the old dated call.
    import * as React from 'react'
    //import React from "react";
    import {useState, Dispatch} from "react";

    //this context has the job to provide feedback messages to all components who might need them. 23 august 2020

    export interface IProviderProps {
      children?:any;
     
    }
    //create the object for the message state 
    type MessageContextState = {
     message: string; 
     messageType: string; 
     mVisible:boolean;
    }
    //object to define the message and setMessage
    type messageContextValue = {
      fbMessage: MessageContextState;
      setFbMessage: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<MessageContextState>>;
    };

    export interface FeedBackMessages {
     message: string,
     messageType: string,
     mVisible : boolean
    } 
     //this is initializing the context with default values
    export const FeedbackContext = React.createContext<messageContextValue | undefined> (undefined);


    //this replaces FeedbackContext.Provider in the app
    export const FeedbackProvider = (props:IProviderProps)=>{
     const [fbMessage, setFbMessage] = useState({message:"Blaat",  messageType:"default",mVisible:false});
      return(
      <FeedbackContext.Provider value ={{ fbMessage, setFbMessage}}>
        {props.children}
      </FeedbackContext.Provider>
      )


    }
```

But I still do not understand why it works on Chrome in the browser and not in the Excel add-in?