# TypeScript Interfaces: Property 'A' does not exist on type 'B | null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add TypeScript interface types to the JSON data I'm pulling in. I'm currently receiving the following error in relation to my MachineDetail.tsx file:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'APIContextInterface | null'.
```

**MachineDetail.tsx** (line below is where it's throwing the error)

```
const { data, isLoading } = useContext(APIContext);
```

**apiContext.tsx** (where I'm pulling in API data and storing it in Context)

My TypeScript interface and the Context where I'm holding the data:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

interface APIContextInterface {
  category: string;
  product_details: {
    id: number;
    category: string;
    model: string;
    power: number;
    operating_weight: number;
    description: string;
    image: string;
  };
}

export const APIContext = createContext<APIContextInterface | null>(null);
   
export default function APIContextProvider({ children }) {
  // Initialize state
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // Fetch data
  useEffect(() => {
    let url = "../db.json";
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        setData(response.data.machines);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <APIContext.Provider value={{ data, isLoading }}>
      {children}
    </APIContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The JSON data is structured like so:

```
{
    "machines": [{
            "category": "category name",
            "product_details": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "category": "category name",
                    "model": "224X3",
                    "power": 67.1,
                    "operating_weight": 5849,
                    "description": "desc goes here",
                    "image": "url-link"
                },
             ],
          },
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you defined `APIContext` to be a context containing `APIContextInterface | null`:

```
export const APIContext = createContext<APIContextInterface | null>(null);
```

while you actually provided values of another type. Remember the type you give to `createContext` is always the type you should provide. Hence you should write

```
export const APIContext = createContext<{
  data: APIContextInterface[],
  isLoading: boolean
} | null>(null);
```

instead so as to match your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised because After creating context, your useState can create separate state instead of adding it into your created context.

You can find solution from this answer : [Passing state with useContext in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193424/passing-state-with-usecontext-in-typescript)